# How can I replace multiple strings with rollup-replace

Tags: javascript, rollupjs, transpiler

The first replace works, the second not. I just can't get it from the docs here what to do:
https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/replace

```
export default {
  input: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/build.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },
  plugins: [
    replace(
      { 'originalprefix-': 'myprefix-', delimiters: ['', ''] },
      { 'ABCprefix': 'DEFprefix', delimiters: ['', ''] }
    ),
```

I also tried this, but it seems multiple runs create double replaces:

```
    replace(
      { 'origprefix-': 'myprefix-', delimiters: ['', ''] },
    ),
    replace(
      { 'ABCprefix': 'DEFprefix', delimiters: ['', ''] }
    ),
```

Same here:

```
    replace(
      { 
       'origprefix-': 'myprefix-', delimiters: ['', ''],
       'ABCprefix': 'DEFprefix', delimiters: ['', ''] 
      }
    ),
```

Comment: Solved this by using `rollup-plugin-modify` which allows regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace({ 
    'origprefix-': 'myprefix-',
    'ABCprefix': 'DEFprefix',
    delimiters: ['', ''] 
}),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/first-posts/26249142)